# Retrieve the subscribers id who watched video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Overall Goal: To report possible subscribers who are not active on my YouTube channel.

I'm reading through the YouTube Data API (v3) trying to understand how to retrieve the actual ids who watched a specific video. I know you can get the number of views, but I don't see any call/response that shows you the subscriber ids. Has anyone done this?

So far what I gathered from the docs and Google searching is that this was possible using the Watch History of a subscriber, but that's been deprecated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So I do not believe it's possible to get IDs of users who have watched certain videos but I have a workaround for my use case; reporting inactive subscribers. This is not the best but it'll get me somewhere.

YouTube's API is very limiting now, but by calling the Subscriptions API

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&mySubscribers=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

I am able to get all subscribers with their channel IDs. Then after saving their IDs, I can check each one's statistics by making this call:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=[SUB_ID]&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]`

which I receive a response like this:

```
{
    "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
    "etag": "\"j6xRRd8dTPVVptg711_CSPADRfg/AZpZT_vQrY3UTi57ia_QqrKdc8c\"",
    "pageInfo": {
        "totalResults": 1,
        "resultsPerPage": 1
     },
    "items": [
        {
            "kind": "youtube#channel",
            "etag": "\"something\"",
            "id": "[SUB_ID]",
            "statistics": {
                "viewCount": "0",
                "commentCount": "0",
                "subscriberCount": "1",
                "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
                "videoCount": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Using this response (see "statistics"), I am making a generalization that if the subscriber has no comments AND no videos, then it's a safe bet that they are not active.